# Update Lambda function arguments on button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

I've snipped out parts of the code, as i suspect the answer is quite newbie :)

I am trying to validate the input in the Entry by clicking the button (which references to a validation funciton). However the path_directory-variable are not updated (it keeps the initial value).

How do I update it when the button is clicked?

```
directory = tk.Entry(entry_frame)

validate_button= tk.Button(paths_frame, text='Next', command=lambda path_directory=directory.get(): self.validate_path(path_directory)) 

def validate_path(self, path_directory):
        if path.exists(path_directory):
            print('# Path validation succuessful: ', path_directory)
        else: 
            print('# Path validation failed: ', path_directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are getting the value only on lambda init. Simply use a function, not lambda, like this:

```
def validate_click():
    path_directory=directory.get()
    self.validate_path(path_directory)
validate_button= tk.Button(paths_frame, text='Next', command=validate_click)
```

Hope that's helpful!